# Is there a single word for a cache that is read-through, but not a write-back cache?

Tags: naming

I am looking for a single word (or a phrase) which may be standard to describe a cache that is read-through, but not a write-back, Basically, it reads data from the underlying DB or data store, but does not write the results back to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Read-only cache** seems to capture what you're describing.

For example, one [IBM database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPK3V_7.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.universalcacheuserguide.doc/doc/features.cache.type.html) defines it this way.

> When configured as a read-only cache, the data is owned by the backend database. This ownership means that the data stored in the cache cannot be modified by the application. In read-only configuration, applications can modify the data directly in the backend database and changes can be synchronized to the cache, transaction by transaction, automatically or on-demand. This configuration is ideal for applications that require fast access to data that changes occasionally, such as price lists, or reference or lookup data.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) on caching also uses the phrase *read-only* a couple of times.